# VB.net Faster way of creating folders, subfolders and Excel files within those folders

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, excel

I'm using VB 2010, SQL Server 2012 Excel 2010.

The users at my company have a requirement to use specific Excel report for hospitals and doctors.

I have a table in SQL Server that contains certain data and also the name of the person who is assigned to that hospital/doctor office, hospital name and lastly the address of the hospital name/doctor office.

The folders can have the following structure:

```
C:\Test\assignee name\hospital name\hospital or doctor address\hospital or doctor address.xlsx
```

Alternatively the hospital name could be blank ending with the following structure:

```
C:\Test\assignee name\hospital or doctor address\hospital or doctor address.xlsx
```

Here is the code I have until now, but it takes 4 hours to get only 4 of these assignee folders and reports generated.

I need to have 26 assignee folders, 3831 subfolders, 7281 files.

I'm looking for a faster way of doing this, please.

Here is my code:

**Private Sub Create_CQM_Folders_VB()**

```
Private Sub Create_CQM_Folders_VB()
    Dim t1 As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim t2 As DateTime
    Dim duration As TimeSpan        
    Dim connectionString As String = "server=SERVER1;Initial Catalog=DATABASE1;Integrated Security=SSPI"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT distinct [Chase Assignment],[folder grouping],standardprovideraddress2 from SITES_Assigned", conn)
        Dim count As Integer = 1
        conn.Open()

        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        //myReader = command.ExecuteReader
        While (myReader.Read())
            stringvar = Trim(myReader(0).ToString)
            stringvar2 = Trim(myReader(1).ToString)
            stringvar3 = Trim(myReader(2).ToString)

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringvar2) Then
                MkDir("C:\test\" & stringvar & "\" & stringvar3)
                Call Create_Main_CQM_Report()

                If Val(xlAppSumm.Version) < 12 Then
                    //You use Excel 2000-2003
                    FileExtStr = ".xls" : FileFormatNum = -4143
                Else
                    //You use Excel 2007
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx" : FileFormatNum = 51
                End If

                //save each of the reports to their corresponding paths

                Dim xlsxfilename As String
                xlsxfilename = stringvar3
                xlWorkBookSumm.SaveAs("C:\test\" & stringvar & "\" & stringvar3 _
                         & "\" & xlsxfilename & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum)

                xlWorkBookSumm.Close()
                xlAppSumm.Quit()
                // End If
            Else
                MkDir("C:\test\" & stringvar & "\" & stringvar2 & "\" & stringvar3)
                Call Create_Main_CQM_Report()

                If Val(xlAppSumm.Version) < 12 Then
                    //You use Excel 2000-2003
                    FileExtStr = ".xls" : FileFormatNum = -4143
                Else
                    //You use Excel 2007
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx" : FileFormatNum = 51
                End If

                //save each of the reports to their corresponding paths
                Dim xlsxfilename As String
                xlsxfilename = stringvar3

                xlWorkBookSumm.SaveAs("C:\test\" & stringvar & "\" & stringvar2 & "\" & stringvar3 _
                         & "\" & xlsxfilename & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum)

                xlWorkBookSumm.Close()
                xlAppSumm.Quit()
                //End If
                count = count + 1
            End If
        End While
        conn.Close()
    End Using

    t2 = DateTime.Now
    duration = t2.Subtract(t1)

    //Get the difference and display it   
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Elapsed time:  {0} Hours, {1} Minutes, {2} Seconds", duration.Hours, duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds))
    MessageBox.Show("All reports have been created")
End Sub
```

**Private Sub Create_Main_CQM_Report()**

```
Private Sub Create_Main_CQM_Report()
    //show CQM report in datagridview
    Try
        Dim connString As String = "server=SERVER1;Initial Catalog=DATABASE1;Integrated Security=SSPI"
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        Dim dbComd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from RPT_ASSIGNED_REPORTS order by [chase assignment], [folder grouping], standardprovideraddress2", conn)

        conn.Open()
        dbComd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        // dbComd.CommandTimeout = 900

        Dim adapters As New SqlDataAdapter(dbComd)
        Dim dset As New DataSet()
        adapters.Fill(dset)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables(0)
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False

        Dim dv As New DataView()
        dv = dset.Tables(0).DefaultView
        // get the DataView from a DataTable
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringvar2) Then
            dv.RowFilter = "[chase assignment] = '" & stringvar & "' and standardprovideraddress2 = '" & stringvar3 & "'"
        Else
            dv.RowFilter = "[chase assignment] = '" & stringvar & "' and [folder grouping] = '" & stringvar2 & "' and standardprovideraddress2 = '" & stringvar3 & "'"
        End If

        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while retrieving records from table..." & ex.Message, "Retrieve Records")
    Finally
        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Records retrieved")
    End Try

    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim curr_date As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy HH.mm.ss")

    copyAlltoClipboard()
    xlAppSumm = New Excel.Application()
    xlWorkBookSumm = xlAppSumm.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheetSumm = xlWorkBookSumm.Sheets("Sheet1")
    xlWorkSheetSumm.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll)
    //xlWorkSheetSumm.Columns("A:A").Delete()
    xlAppSumm.Visible = False

    With xlWorkSheetSumm
        //save each of the reports to their corresponding paths
        .Columns("A:AN").EntireColumn.AutoFit()
    End With

    My.Computer.Clipboard.Clear()

    //Clear datagridview for next sheet
    Call Clear_DGV1()
End Sub
```

Comment: TL:DR. You should debug your code to detect what function is taking the most of the time. Then we can focus on that problem. Try with this [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295551/tracking-duration-of-functions-calls-in-vb-net)  ... then you should read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Some functions like CopyAllToClipboard() and MkDir() are not shown there. And, I suppose you are getting too much memory in your SQL statements since I cannot see any memory cleaning process - try to utilize the *Using - End Using* syntax in the SQL functions to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Wont help with performance but improve readability and maintenance. Instead of having a big `IF`  code  like `if String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringvar2)` or `If Val(xlAppSumm.Version) < 12` create separated function like `process(stringvar2)` and `checkExcelVersion(xlAppSumm.Version)`

Comment: Hi Juan Carlos! Readability is not my problem here, the problem is that this takes too long to process. I had a similar program in VBA and the same number of files and folders took only 2 hours and 40 minutes to process to completion. I don't understand why it takes so much longer in VB.net. Unfortunately, I have to stop using the Excel VBA, since they do not allow us to use it at work anymore.

Comment: Hi David BS! The code for CopyAlltoClipboard is as follows     Private Sub copyAlltoClipboard()

        DataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText
        DataGridView1.SelectAll()
        Dim dataObj As DataObject = DataGridView1.GetClipboardContent()
        If dataObj IsNot Nothing Then
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj)
        End If

    End Sub

Comment: @TammyG That was a recomendation so you can analyze your problem for pieces. For perfomance you have to tell us what function is taking the most time to execute. So we can have an idea where to work. Maybe your excel files are too big. Maybe you are doing too many connection to db. Maybe your db is on China and internet is real slow.

Comment: @Juan Carlos, you are correct that the db is not close, since we are in NYC and db server is in Florida. I used the timer you suggested and it was taking 46 seconds for the first folder and Excel to get generated, 31 seconds to the second one. I stopped it and started it again and the times changes to 11 secs the first one and 7 secs the second one.

Comment: @Juan Carlos, also I'm getting this error randomly "The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x5d9650 to COM context 0x5d97c0 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages.This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time.To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles)"

Comment: @David BS I changed the code to use 'using ....end using' to connect to the db.